# Erro ao excutar navegador = webdriver.Chrome() no Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo um código para rodar no chrome pelo selenium, e está dando erro.
Segue o que escrevi nas linhas:

```
import selenium
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
from openpyxl import workbook, load_workbook

tabelacmr = load_workbook("CMRS.xlsx")
aba_ativa = tabelacmr.active
aba_ativa = tabelacmr.active

for A in (aba_ativa["A"]):
    navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
```

e está dando esse erro:

```
   SessionNotCreatedException                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [47], in <cell line: 11>()
      9 aba_ativa = tabelacmr.active
     11 for A in (aba_ativa["A"]):
---> 12     navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
     13     navegador.get("https://lenovo-nitro-prod.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?forceUCI=1&pagetype=apps")
     14     #navegador.find_element(By.XPATH,

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py:69, in WebDriver.__init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, service, keep_alive)
     66 if not service:
     67     service = Service(executable_path, port, service_args, service_log_path)
---> 69 super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
     70                  port, options,
     71                  service_args, desired_capabilities,
     72                  service_log_path, service, keep_alive)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py:92, in ChromiumDriver.__init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, service, keep_alive)
     89 self.service.start()
     91 try:
---> 92     super().__init__(
     93         command_executor=ChromiumRemoteConnection(
     94             remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     95             browser_name=browser_name, vendor_prefix=vendor_prefix,
     96             keep_alive=keep_alive, ignore_proxy=_ignore_proxy),
     97         options=options)
     98 except Exception:
     99     self.quit()

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:277, in WebDriver.__init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    275 self._authenticator_id = None
    276 self.start_client()
--> 277 self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:370, in WebDriver.start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    368 w3c_caps = _make_w3c_caps(capabilities)
    369 parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps}
--> 370 response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    371 if 'sessionId' not in response:
    372     response = response['value']

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:435, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    433 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    434 if response:
--> 435     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    436     response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    437         response.get('value', None))
    438     return response

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:247, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    245         alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    246     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 247 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 103
Current browser version is 107.0.5304.106 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00AC5FD3+2187219]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A5E6D1+1763025]
    Ordinal0 [0x00973E78+802424]
    Ordinal0 [0x009951F9+938489]
    Ordinal0 [0x00990DDC+921052]
    Ordinal0 [0x0098E691+910993]
    Ordinal0 [0x009C17F0+1120240]
    Ordinal0 [0x009C144A+1119306]
    Ordinal0 [0x009BC9A6+1100198]
    Ordinal0 [0x00996F80+946048]
    Ordinal0 [0x00997E76+949878]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D690C2+2721218]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D5AAF0+2662384]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B5137A+526458]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B50416+522518]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A64EAB+1789611]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A697A8+1808296]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A69895+1808533]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A726C1+1844929]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x768FFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77737BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77737B8E+238]
```

Eu já baixei o webdriver do chrome novamente, reinstalei o selenium, tentei passar o caminho da pasta para ele mas não funcionou, podem me ajudar por favor?

Comment: olá... *"This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 103
Current browser version is 107.0.5304.106"* já tentou entender o que isso significa? é problema de versão

Comment: é incompatibilidade de versão, o driver ta usando uma versão atual enquanto o navegador em teu sistema esta em uma outra versão abaixo do que o driver requer.

Answer (score -2):

No final do erro possui a seguinte mensagem

> SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 103

> Current browser version is 107.0.5304.106 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Você comentou que já atualizou o Chromedriver, mas tudo da a entender que é uma questão de atualizar o próprio Chromedriver.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Salve! A questão não é apenas de "baixar novamente", e sim de baixar a versão adequada do driver. Inclusive, nem é a versão do Selenium. É só o chromedriver, que é um pequeno executável na pasta do selenium.

Pelo erro no final, você está tentando rodar um navegador na versão 107 com uma versão do chromedriver que só suporta até a 103.

O que você tem que fazer é o seguinte:

**1.** Abra o chrome -> menu reticências -> ajuda -> acerca do google chrome.

**2.** Na janela Acerca do Chrome, vai aparecer a versão (a minha está 107.0.5304.88). Raramente importam as subversões, geralmente é só o primeiro número, no meu caso, 107. De acordo com seu erro, você deve estar com a 107 também.

**3.** Então, você **não vai reinstalar o Selenium**. Você vai apenas baixar o chromedriver correspondente a essa versão, no site oficial, https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads.

**4.** No site, você vai baixar um arquivo compactado correspondente à sua versão. Deste, você vai extrair um executável, chamado `chromedriver.exe`.

**5.** Vá até a pasta onde o Selenium está instalado e procure onde fica o arquivo chromedriver.exe (o da pasta do Selenium, não confunda com o que você acabou de baixar). No meu computador, é na pasta raiz do Selenium, mas minha versão não é Python, então pode ser diferente.

**6.** Tudo que você precisa fazer é `substituir o chromedriver que existe lá pelo novo que você baixou`, adequado à versão do seu navegador. Não é pra colar o arquivo compactado, e sim o `chromedriver.exe` que você extraiu do arquivo compactado .zip. Não é necessário guardar o anterior, porque ele não será mais útil (e as versões anteriores, caso um dia você precise, podem ser baixadas no mesmo site acima).

**Em tempo: usar o chromedriver tem esse inconveniente. A cada atualização do chrome, o chromedriver precisa ser atualizado. Eu tive que treinar uma pessoa num organização-cliente para poder fazer isso, porque aproximadamente a cada 1,5 ou 2 meses o chrome atualiza, o usuário acha que o software bugou, mas na verdade é só atualizar o chromedriver: é necessário repetir esse processo.**

**No caso do Selenium que eu uso (é o do Visual Basic), há uma subpasta `scripts`, onde há scripts para testar se o Selenium está conseguindo controlar os navegadores (ou seja, se os drivers estão na versão correta). Se na sua versão houver uma pasta parecida, verifique se não há um arquivo chamado `StartChrome`. Ele serve para testar se o Selenium está controlando adequadamente o Chrome. Se estiver, ele abrirá o navegador, com uma popup dizendo que está tudo certo.**

Answer (score -3):

Como já falaram, é preciso usar o ChromeDriver na mesma versão do chrome. Mas não é necessário baixar toda vez que atualiza, use o código abaixo para o driver ser baixado automaticamente toda vez que a versão do navegador mudar:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),  options=options)
```

Answer (score -3):

Eu tive um problema similar, utilizando Java. Eu precisei atualizar a última versão do Chrome (114.0.5735.199 (Versão oficial) 32 bits) e atualizei as bibliotecas do selenium web driver para a última (4.10). Nesta versão não é necessário mais utilizar o Chrome driver.